# "Remember Me" functionality doesn't work properly in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am getting number of complaints regarding login form's "Remember Me" functionality, users are upset that they have to log-in every single time and the system doesn’t remember them, even though it is checked to remember them in their browser.

I am using "Login With Ajax" plugin to handle the login functionality.

Comment: Have you replicated the problem? Does it happen just on one browser? Maybe the affected users have special cookie settings?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Yes, I replicated the problem. No, it happens on all browsers on different different systems. In my database, have more than 70000 users, so its not possible to check the cookie settings.

Comment: OK. Nevertheless, I would estimate that the brevity of this question means you have a 5% chance of someone guessing what the problem is. That is a very slim chance indeed. To improve your odds of getting a useful answer, readers are going to need a lot more information from you.

Comment: Have a look to see whether you get the cookies you expect for the different kinds of login. You should get a session cookie for an ordinary login and a dated cookie for a "remember me" login. Check your cookie storage in your browser for each case (and clear your cookies between each try). I would guess there is a problem with setting the dated cookie. Maybe the tickbox value is not reaching the plugin?

Comment: I would also suggest that you set up WordPress on your local machine, so you can debug this properly. You may need to add some temporary debugging statements in the plugin code to see what is (not) being called.

Comment: @halfer Ok, I will try your solutions as well.

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour of WordPress' "Remember Me" functionality is to extend the cookie lifetime to 14 days. You can extend this even more with the 'auth_cookie_expiration' filter. (Add to your theme's functions.php file)  ...

```
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'extend_login_cookie' );

function extend_login_cookie( $expirein ) {
    return 31556926; // 1 year in seconds (Adjust to your needs)
}
```

I'm sure there are also a [plethora of plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remember-me-controls/) that can help you along these lines as well ....

Comment: I see this as an example of how developers think differently than users. Many users expect the "username" to be filled out when "Remember me" is checked.